# Excel worksheet triggers and events

Tags: vba, excel

In one of my workbooks I use both the `Worksheet_Activate()` trigger and also the `Workbook_SheetActivate` trigger. I'm using the latter as an over riding handler to control which users can see which worksheets. Using the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal ws As Object)
Dim HigherAccess As String

HigherAccess = "Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3"
If InStr(1, HigherAccess, ws.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    If UserList.Count = 0 Or ThisUser = "" Then Call UserDL

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        On Error GoTo err

        If Not UserList.item(ThisUser)(7) = "Employee" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Landing Page").Activate
            MsgBox "You do not have permission to view this." & vbNewLine _
            & "If this is an error please contact xxxx"
        End If
End If

Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox "An Error has occurred. The application will now refresh"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Landing Page").Activate
End Sub
```

My issue is is that the `Worksheet_Acivate()` trigger seems to fire before the `Workbook_SheetActivate` one. Is there anyway to change the order in which these fire?

Comment: Move the code from `Workbook_SheetActivate()` to the beginning of `Worksheet_Acivate()`?

Comment: @OlleSjögren But then I'd have to repeat the same code 5-10 times when I could handle it in the `ThisWorkbook` sheet?

Comment: if it is indeed an issue of which code fires, first. you could write the code into a Public Sub (in a separate module), then just call the code at each `Worksheet_Activate` event.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I had thought of that but was just wondering if there were any rules as to how the triggers worked as there must then be a decision somewhere to fire the worksheet events before the workbook. I'll probably take your approach if there isn't a way to change it. Thanks

Comment: I was just looking to find the `event order` but haven't found anything yet ... but I will post a link if I do find something. I would think, as you do, that there must be information on what fires first (and why).

Comment: You could probably create a custom class and `WithEvents` to create an override for the `Worksheet_Activate()` event and assign it to all sheets in a loop - but the bigger question here is, why are you using that event when you can access the `ws` argument in the `Workbook_SheetActivate()` event?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks - I did have a look but couldn't find much.

Comment: @MacroMan Sorry Macro not sure I understand. I'm using the `Workbook_SheetActivate(ws as object)` for the code above, then I've got the `Worksheet_Activate() triggering for code specific to the worksheet

Comment: @Tom So my question is, rather than having code specific to each sheet in the `Worksheet_Activate()` events - why not just test the sheet name in the `Workbook_SheetActivate()` event and run the required code based on the name - there's no need to use both events?

Comment: Have a look at the mighty Chuck Pearson on [Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx). Specifically this *The order of events is from the least significant object (the Sheet) upwards through the most significant object (the Application).* under **Order of Events**

Comment: @MacroMan I think I'm with you - so put all of the code for each sheet into the `Workbook_SheetActivate()` and execute depending on the sheet.

Comment: Also, giving credit to @ScottHoltzman and his research effort - the order in which events are fire is determined by the object's hierarchy, as Chip explains in his article the order of events is processed from the lowest "child" object upwards - imagine a  tree/node setup to help visualise

Comment: Brilliant - thanks guys :) MacroMan Hadn't though of doing that so thanks for another way. @ScottHoltzman Thanks for finding that. Is comforting to know there is an order I could only find saying 'there was no guaranteed order' [ref](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_events_sequence.htm) If you want to put an answer up I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Events are fired from the "smallest" object (in the Excel Object Model) to the "largest" object (worksheet to application), you cannot change the order of the events fired.

You can, however, work within that order to accomplish your goals, as @MacroMan has stated with his example of testing the `Worksheet` that caused the `Change Event` in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event.

See Chuck Pearson's tutorial on [Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) for more information.